How to add priority task to celery queue without fetching disabling
I have a celery worker, with concurrency set to 1, which takes tasks from RabbitMQ. I want to make a system with only one queue in a single concurrency setup, so, all tasks are going to be added in main queue.
About the task - its just a loop where we update state with task.update_state().
@c_app.task(bind=True)
def task(self):
    n = 20
    for i in range(0, n):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'done': i, 'total': n})
        print('working')
        time.sleep(1)
    return n

In parallel I have two services.

Celery-beat service, which creates 1000 tasks (amount as example).
FastAPI service, which provides two endpoints:

create task with TOP priority and add it to the main queue
get actual info about active task and scheduled tasks (by using inspect())



So, FastAPI can be asked about:

current active task progress - inspect().active()
how many tasks remain - inspect().scheduled()

Question: How can I add task with higher priority to the queue, which already scheduled the tasks to the worker?
Here is my what I've tried:
Celery config:
from celery.schedules import crontab
from kombu import Queue, Exchange

broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
result_backend = 'db+postgresql://admin:root@localhost/celery_test_db'

worker_concurrency = 1
timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'
enable_utc = False
result_extended = True

beat_schedule = {
    'add-5-tasks-every-month': {
        'task': 'celery_app.tasks.add_5_tasks',
        'options': {'queue': 'celery_q'},
        'schedule': 20.0
    },
}

broker_transport_options = {'queue_order_strategy': 'priority'}
task_queues = (
    Queue("celery_q", Exchange("celery_q"), routing_key="celery_q", queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 9}),
)

Here is my Celery-Beat task for adding big amount of tasks with low priority:
@c_app.task
def add_5_tasks():
    for _ in range(800):
        task.apply_async(countdown=1, queue='celery_q', priority=1)

Here is my FastAPI end-point for adding high priority task, which, as I expect, should be executed right after current task is being completed.
@f_app.post("/add-task/")
def add_task():
    task_ = task.apply_async(priority=9, countdown=1, queue='celery_q')
    print('Task added with high priority:', task_.id)
    return {'task_id': task_.id,
            'message': 'Task added with high priority'}

And the "core" of the "current_progress" end-point which returns current progress and scheduled tasks:
i = c_app.control.inspect()
scheduled = i.scheduled()
reserved = i.reserved()
active = i.active()

Problem: the prioritisation doesn't work as I expected.
It works only if I add these setting in the config:
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
task_acks_late = True

But, it causes inspect().scheduled() to become absolutely useless, as we fetch only one task in a row, so worker thinks that we have only one task in a schedule. So, instead of list of tasks we can see a single task in inspect().scheduled()
MAIN QUESTION: How to enable prioritisation and get all info about scheduled tasks from inspect().scheduled()?
